# Make a JQuery Highlight Bar thinner

Tags: jquery-ui

I am currently using JQuery UI for several UI elements on my site.  Is there a way to make the highlight and error bars thinner?

I am referring to the two things found in the lower-right [here](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

I imagine there should be a CSS property that I can change to fix this, I just can't seem to find it.

**Solution:** `.ui-state-highlight p { margin-top:3px; margin-bottom:3px; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the jQuery page there is a margin on the `p` tag in the content. It should conform to the content that you are inserting. Can you post the problem you are having.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, that was exactly what I needed.  Basically, I wanted to override the default width of the bar.  So, knowing that JQuery has a margin set on p, I was able to override it like this:

.ui-state-highlight p { margin-top:3px; margin-bottom:3px; }